# get the custom taxonomy name?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

In my `functions.php` I have this hook :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'display_category_list',20 ); 

function display_category_list() {
  wc_get_template( 'woocommerce/single-product/single-product-top- 
       content.php' );
 }
```

But I need to activate this hook ONLY on products pages that belongs to a certain custom taxonomy.

so I need to find out in each product what is it's custom taxonomy.
Now I have this code :

```
  $taxonomy_objects = get_object_taxonomies( 'product', 'objects' );
   print_r( $taxonomy_objects);
```

This is what I got:

```
 Array ( [product_category] => WP_Taxonomy Object ( [name] => 
 product_category [label] => Product Categories [labels] => stdClass Object 
( [name] => Product Categories [singular_name] => Product Category 
[search_items] => Search Product Categories [popular_items] => [all_items] 
 => All Product Categories [parent_item] => Parent Product Category 
 [parent_item_colon] => Parent Product Category: [edit_item] => Edit Product 
  Category........
```

This is what I need

http://prntscr.com/j3o06n

how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if term exists, [see here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'display_category_list',20 ); 

function display_category_list() {

  global $post;
  $term = 'term_name'; // Term name string or array
  $taxonomy = 'product_cat'; // your taxonomy

  if( has_term($term, $taxonomy, $post) ){ // if post belongs to term(s) 

     wc_get_template( 'woocommerce/single-product/single-product-top- 
       content.php' );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you :) but now the 'if statement (terms) ' blocks  the "wc_get_template" in all shop/products pages.

Comment: I need to check if the current  product page belongs to a specific taxonomy, If I am not mistaken , your if statement output terms regardless of the current product page.?

Comment: You can check if the product belongs to a taxonomy by checking whether current product belongs to any term of the taxonomy. Did you try to put the term's slug in `$term = array( 'term1', 'term2', 'term3' )` and `$taxonomy = 'product_catetory'` , if you have taxonomy `product_category` otherwise WooCommerce default taxonomy is `product_cat`.

Comment: I think maybe the problem is where to put the if statement, if I put it inside the product loop , it's perfect, because the object returned is indeed the product object. but for styling purposes I need to run this outside the product loop, (banner on top of the page,before the loop)    .and then a totally different object is returned:(

Comment: you don't need to put inside loop

Comment: @tal `woocommerce_before_single_product` is inside the loop. Are you not putting this code in a hook anymore? If you *are* putting it outside the loop, replace `$post` in the 3rd argument of `has_term()` with `get_queried_object_id()`, to check terms on the main product being queried, regardless of the loop.